# How to reduce server "Wait" time?

Tags: javascript, performance, apache, networking

I am trying to optimize my site's speed and I'm using the great tool at [pingdom.com](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/).  Right now, over 50% of the time it takes to load the page is "Wait" time as shown in the screenshot below.  What can I do to reduce this?  Also, how typical is this figure?  are there benchmarks on this?  Thanks!

[image: high server wait time]

**EDIT:**
Ok.. let me clarify a few things.  There are no server side scripts or database calls going on. Just HTML, CSS, JS, and images.  I have already done some things like push js to the end of the body tag to get parallel downloads.  I am aware that the main.html and templates.html are adding to the overall wait time by being done synchronously after js.js downloads, that's not the problem.  I am just surprised at how much "wait" time there is for each request.  Does server distance affect this?  what about being on a shared server, does that affect the wait time?  Is there any low-hanging fruit to remedy those issues?

[image]

Comment: This isn't really a programming-related question.  Try http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 60):

The most common reason for this in the case of Apache is the usage of DNS Reversal Lookup. What this means is that the server tries to figure out what the name of your machine is, each time you make a request. This can take several seconds, and that explains why you have a long WAIT time and then a very quick load, because the matter is not about bandwidth.

The obvious solution for this is to disable hostnamelookup in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
HostnameLookups Off
```

However...this is usually NOT enough. The fact is that in many cases, apache still does a reversal lookup even when you have disabled host name lookup, so you need to take a careful look at each line of your apache config. In particular, one of the most common reasons for this are LOGS. By default on many red hat - centos installations, the log format includes %h which stands for "hostname", and requires apache to do a reverse lookup. You can see this here:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
```

You should change those %h for %a to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks mate.. Any source recommendation for tips like this?

Comment: @ÜnsalKorkmaz Here you go http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html

EDIT: Sorry, I misread. Thought you said "any resource recommendation".

Comment: ```HostnameLookups``` was off but the ```LogFormat``` was the culprit. I got 50% improvement by changing %h to %a.

Comment: Same here, 50% improvement.

Comment: I'm facing same problem. I'm using wordpress and site is hosted on shared host. I'm unable to find the location of file, where i can do those changes. Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: It did not make any changes after changing from %h to %a

Comment: 50% improvement on my side too :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple server requests which the page is waiting on, you can make sure that those server requests are sent asynchronously in parallel so that you are serializing them.

The slowest possible way to fetch multiple requests is to send one request, wait for its response, send the next request, wait for its response, etc...  It's usually much faster to send all requests asynchronously and then process all responses as they arrive.  This shortens the total wait time to the longest wait time for any single request rather than the cumulative wait time of all requests.

If you are only making one single request, then all you can do on the client-side of things is to make sure that the request is sent to the server as early as possible in the page loading sequence so that other parts of the page can be doing their business while the request is processing, thus getting the initial request started sooner (and thus finishing sooner).

Answer (score 1):

The wait time, also known as [time to first byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_To_First_Byte) is how long it takes for the server to send the first byte from when the connection is initiated. If this is high, it means your server has got to do a lot of work to render the page before sending it. We need more information about what your site is doing to render the page.

Comment: Very well, this could also have to do with the access-time on your HDD/RAID. I have had SSD-servers with a lower time to first byte (TTFB), and the websites did really load faster.

Comment: The server may have to do a lot of work, but it may equally have to do a lot of waiting. You need to break down what that elapsed time consists of, before knowing what to tackle for the biggest wins.

Answer (score 0):

TTFB is directly influenced by "physical" distance between browser and server. CDN proxy is the best way to shorten said distance. This, coupled with native caching capabilities, will help provide swifter response by loading cached object from the nearest POP (point of placement) location.

The effect will depend on user geo-location and CDN's spread. Still, you can expect [significant improvement](http://www.incapsula.com/the-incapsula-blog/item/718-what-incapsula-free-did-for-my-site), 50%-70% or more.

Speaking from experience, I saw cases in which 90% of content was cached and deliver directly from proxy placed on a different continent, from the other side of the globe.

Answer (score -1):

This is an issue with the server... According to Pingdom, "The web browser is waiting for data from the server" is what defines the "Wait" time.

There isn't much you can do from a javascript or code end to fix this.

Comment: This is not what the wait time is.