# Slow Page Load Times - Long 'Wait' Period According to Pingdom

Tags: webserver, page-load-time

My page load times have been wildly fluctuating, and sometimes it takes so long to serve a page that I get a server timed out error, even during relatively quiet times of day for my site.

I have been using pingdom to check page load times and to try and find where the problem lies.

It seems when a page loads normally (in approx 6 seconds), there is a 1.63 second 'Wait' Time for the main html file, before it starts receiving the file.
You can see this here:
http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/GEoqJlVdZ/http://www.bluedogposters.com.au/shopdisplayproducts.asp?id=11&cat=Movies

But 2 minutes later, when the same page is taking 17 seconds to load, there is an 11.7 second Wait Time before starting to receive this same html file.
You can see an example here:
http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/he2L5Jhgz/http://www.bluedogposters.com.au/shopdisplayproducts.asp?id=11&cat=Movies

Do you know what can cause this difference in the Wait times because it seems this is the reason my site has been so slow recently.
Accoring to the Waterfall chart, there is nothing else happening, so why the Wait?

Is it more likely to be a code or server issue? 
I found some useful info here [How to reduce server "Wait" time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938682/how-to-reduce-server-wait-time)

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need a tool that can dig into the backend performance, something like New Relic might help - they do a free month trial.

There's obviously some variation in performance going on but whether it's related to load or other factors is really hard to discern without digging deeply.

Comment: Thanks Andy, according to the video it will reveal the reason the site is going slow, so I'll definitely give that a go.

Comment: Hi Andy, unfortunately New Relic does not work on ASP Classic sites, do you know of any other good tools?

Comment: Hmm, you might have to go the hard way and use PAL (http://pal.codeplex.com/) to dig into what's going on during page generation. Also look at the stats for the SQL queries e.g. which queries are most disk IO, CPU, memory etc. and are they being executed during page generation.

Answer (score 0):

You should try new relic anyway, it will still give you a good answer even on an ASP classic site. I have used it on windows servers before to figure out why an app was running slow.